# API Monitoring on a specific process

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, monitoring, process

Just like to monitor some windows api functions in my process named "myprocess.exe" .
I Know wide system hooks (Global hooks) can do such thing but I would like to setup it on a **specific process only** .
Any sample code in C/C++/Python would be helpful, also there are tutorials that can help me it would be nice to share it here with me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Detours" from Microsoft Research. Also, you can do this with a debugger by setting a breakpoint on the api functions of interest, dumping the arguments, running to the return address, and then dumping the return value. This has the drawback of being a more manual process. Finally, windbg (from the "Debugging Tools for Windows" package) has the wt command which will trace function calls to any depth you specify.

Comment: Detours has a rather restrictive license. I'd consider http://newgre.net/ncodehook and http://newgre.net/ninjectlib as well as PyDbg.

Answer (score 0):

http://easyhook.codeplex.com/ has a simple C++ API and C# (.NET) API.
supports 64bit.

If you just want to monitor for research you can use winapioverride32 (http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/). It provides API monitoring and it is open source!